# How do I prevent to be redirected with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl

I'm developing a form in which requires to submit the collected data to a third party website, in the form of: http://www.domain.com/page?key=value&key2=value2

I decide to use cURL as I have not found an alternative that convince me.

The problem that I'm running is that once the form is submitted, cURL is executed but I'm being redirected to the domain that I specified. Instead, I want to redirect the user to a confirmation page within my domain and not to the third party website.

Here is an example of the code that I'm using:

```
$URL="otherserver.domain.com";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://$URL"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "key=value2&key2=value2&key3=value3");
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

How can I prevent from being redirected to otherserver.domain.com?

Please feel free to let me know if you think that instead of using cURL, there is a better way to submit the data to the third party website.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <?php
$url = "http://***.."; 
$ch = curl_init($url);
$opts = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
          CURLOP_HEADER => 1,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 0,
          CURLOPT_POST => 1,
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "foo=ba"); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, $opts); 
echo curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please write an example? I'm still getting redirected regardless I use 0 or 1 for CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION. Actually I'm getting the content of the url that I specified. All I want is just to submit the collected data

Comment: I found the problem, and it was due to the third party website that was causing the redirection.

Answer (score 9):

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

will not output result

and

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
```

will ignore redirects (so when http://google.com/ transfers you to https://google.us/ this will ignore it)

Comment: I need to run a URL from a .php file. I don't need to grab its output or do anything. All I want to do is just call a URL e.g.: http://www.domain.com so that the server receives a request for the URL and executes the request. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Additional to the measures provided on the accepted answer, also make sure you are escaping the output if you are echoing it.

For example, Instead of:

```
$lastResponse = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $lastResponse;
```

Use:

```
$lastResponse = curl_exec( $ch );
echo htmlentities($lastResponse ,ENT_QUOTES);
```

This solved the issue in my case cause there was a JS redirect on the response I was getting.

*I know this is an old question but is the first result online, so hopefully this helps someone as it did for me when I found it on a forum after a couple hours of serching.*

Comment: You mean `<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=https://www.example.com" />` , right ?

Comment: Oh I get it, you mean a redirect by JS like `document.location = "https://example.com"`

Comment: @Accountantم  Correct, anything that can cause a redirection should be escaped.